# How can I loop animation in Blender through Viewer Node

Tags: rendering, animation, node-editor, looping

I've got a model running through a pixelate filter using the node editor, and am trying to figure out how to loop it.  I know how to loop it in 3D view, but when I click "render animation" it doesn't loop it in the Viewer node.

Is there a way to do this internally in Blender without having to export it?  Am I just missing something?

I can view and render the image, and I can view and render the animation, but it only goes for a single iteration in the Viewer node.  It will loop continuously in 3D view, but it doesn't use the pixelation effect, as it is not being viewed through the viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already rendered the animation, you can use Blender Video Sequence Editor. Just add clip with the animation and duplicate it as many times you need.
If you want to render already looped animation you can use NLA Editor. Just switch Dope Sheet to Action Editor and click on Push Down to move the animation to NLA Editor. Then switch to NLA Editor and from there you can select the strip and set Repeat in Playback Settings on the right tool shelf, to whatever number you need.

Comment: I'm not sure I explained my question right, because this still doesn't fix my problem.  I'm trying to loop the animation as would occur when you go to Render Animation under the Render tab on the top bar.   This occurs in the UV/Image editor which is where your animation is rendered when you use the viewer output node.  I can run the animation once, but it does not loop.  Is there a way to make it loop in the UV/Image editor when I click render animation, without having to actually render it out everytime I want to see the clip? I can make it loop, but not in the UV/Image editor, as is needed.

Comment: There is no way to see rendered image in UV/Image editor, unless you render it first and the animation is being rendered once from first to the last frame.  You can render this iteration once, and then use the rendered video/set of images to loop it and then you will be able to see it looping in UV/Image editor.

Comment: I figured it out Mzidare, thanks.  I was repeatedly going to "Render Animation" which would play the animation a single time, and refuse to loop.  I completely spaced the difference between "Play Rendered Animation (Ctrl + F11)" and "Render Animation (Ctrl + F12)" seeing as how it would play the animation for one iteration when you render it.  Now the loop works.  Thanks a lot.